# Error: Transaction not confirmed for sendTransaction at rpc connection through http

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

I am trying to send a transaction to a contract deployed on the testnet.

I run the geth  HTTP JSON-RPC, with unlock option and the necessary apis accessible.

When I exec the `web3.eth.sendTransaction` from the console it seems to work fine.

However, that is not the case with the browser (using web3_extended library with chrome), nor with an http client I am using to debug. I get true when executing the `web3.personal.unlockAccount` in the browser (or send the json for the `personal_unlockAccount` in the http client).

But when I send the actual sendTransaction as:

```
 web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: accounts[0], to: contractAddress, data: methodData, gas: 2500000, gasPrice: web3.toWei(0.00001, "ether")}
```

I always get a `200OK` response with:

```
{"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603,"message":"Transaction not confirmed"}}
```

Does anybody know what can be the actual problem?

Comment: did you try to remove that gasPrice ?

Comment: Yes. Same result. Actually I added it after going through forum posts looking for an answer to this.

Comment: eth.pendingTransaction returns what ?

Comment: accounts[0] should be eth.accounts[0] just in case

Comment: About accounts[0], yep, but it is my own var. But thanks.

Comment: eth.pendingTransactions returns a list of the transactions I sent using the console. Many pending, by the way. But not the ones I sent through http. Those are not added to that list.

Comment: Things to check: account locked?, does account have funds?, miner is running?

Comment: I managed to make it work, but I am not sure which is the reason.  I was first running mist and then exec `geth _italic_options attach` and started  the rpc service. The mining was done in mist. And there were enough funds. I now did run the console first, start the mining there and so on, and then, open Mist. So now my transactions get there! But I do not now exactly why, so I will do more tests when I have the time and update accordingly. In any case, it looks the are staying  in pendingTransactions forever... I am trying to guess this now.

Comment: if they stay in pendingtransaction it means they aren't mined, try miner.start(1) to see if it mines them

Comment: Thanks! I did so. But in any case it took these two hours to start mining, reflected in the `getBalance(add)` and then `eth.pendingTransactions` to null. Is this normal?